# NodeJS Canvas - Save only clipped area to new canvas/file

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I'm facing the following challenge:

We got lots of technical drawings with black and white color only. Such a drawing houses multiple objects in a single image.
I coded an edge detector and manage to draw a line / clip the border of each individual object via coordinates (Polygons).

My problem is that I can't find a legit way to save only the clipped areas to individual image files.

I need every object as it's own image (like jpg) without any extra white space around the object.

For testing purposes I'm currently using the image I posted below

[image: multistar.jpg]

This is what my current output looks like, the borders are marked red. I had to invert the colors at the beginning, don't pay it any attention

[image: multistar_currentOutput]

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs') 
var Canvas = require('canvas');

function pixelIsTouching (coord1, coord2){

    if(coord1[0] == coord2[0] && 
      (coord1[1] == coord2[1]+1 ||
      coord1[1] == coord2[1]-1)){
        return true;
    }else if(coord1[1] == coord2[1] && 
            (coord1[0] == coord2[0]+1 ||
            coord1[0] == coord2[0]-1)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/images/multistar.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var img = new Canvas.Image; // Create a new Image
        img.src = data;

        var canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        var pixeldata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        // Filter out any black white noise + Invert 
        for(var x = 0; x < pixeldata.data.length; x+=4){

            if( pixeldata.data[x] > 127) {
                pixeldata.data[x] = 0;
                pixeldata.data[x+1] = 0;
                pixeldata.data[x+2] = 0;
            }else if(pixeldata.data[x] <= 127) {
                pixeldata.data[x] = 255;
                pixeldata.data[x+1] = 255;
                pixeldata.data[x+2] = 255;
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(pixeldata, 0, 0);

        var border = [];

        // Bilddaten pixelweise abarbeiten
        for (x = 0; x < pixeldata.width; x++) {

            for (y = 0; y < pixeldata.height; y++) {

                offset = (pixeldata.width * y + x) * 4;
                r = pixeldata.data[offset];   // rot
                g = pixeldata.data[offset + 1]; // grün
                b = pixeldata.data[offset + 2]; // blau
                a = pixeldata.data[offset + 3]; // Transparenz

                topOffset           = (pixeldata.width * (y-1) + x) * 4;
                rTop                = pixeldata.data[topOffset];

                topRightOffset      = (pixeldata.width * (y-1) + (x+1)) * 4;
                rTopRight           = pixeldata.data[topRightOffset];

                rightOffset         = (pixeldata.width * y + (x+1)) * 4;
                rRight              = pixeldata.data[rightOffset];

                bottomRightOffset   = (pixeldata.width * (y+1) + (x+1)) * 4;
                rBottomRight        = pixeldata.data[bottomRightOffset];

                bottomOffset        = (pixeldata.width * (y+1) + x) * 4;
                rBottom             = pixeldata.data[bottomOffset];

                bottomLeftOffset    = (pixeldata.width * (y+1) + (x-1)) * 4;
                rBottomLeft         = pixeldata.data[bottomLeftOffset];

                leftOffset          = (pixeldata.width * y + (x-1)) * 4;
                rLeft               = pixeldata.data[leftOffset];

                topLeftOffset       = (pixeldata.width * (y-1) + (x-1)) * 4;
                rTopLeft            = pixeldata.data[topLeftOffset];

                // Check around current white pixel if black one is near
                if( r == 255 && rTop == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rTopRight == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rRight == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rBottomRight == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rBottom == 0 || 
                    r == 255 && rBottomLeft == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rLeft == 0 ||
                    r == 255 && rTopLeft == 0){

                        border.push([x, y]);
                    }
            }
        }

        //Order border array
        var borderscounter = 0;
        var borders = [[]];

        var coordFound = undefined;

        borders[borderscounter].push(border[0]);
        border.shift();


        while(border.length > 0){

            coordFound = false;

            for(a = 0; a < border.length; a++){

                lastBlobElement = borders[borderscounter].length-1;

                if(pixelIsTouching(border[a], borders[borderscounter][lastBlobElement])){

                    coordFound = true;
                    borders[borderscounter].push(border[a]);
                    border.splice(a, 1);

                }
            }

            if(coordFound == false && border.length > 0){
                borderscounter++;
                borders[borderscounter] = [];
                borders[borderscounter].push(border[0]);
                border.shift();
            }
        }

        // Draw Line via Border Array

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.beginPath();

        for(b = 0; b < borders.length; b++){
            for(var a = 0; a < borders[b].length; a++){

                // + 0.5 to get rid of blurry lines
                if(a == 0){
                    ctx.moveTo(borders[b][a][0]+0.5, borders[b][a][1]);
                }else{
                    ctx.lineTo(borders[b][a][0]+0.5, borders[b][a][1]);
                }

                if(a == borders[b].length-1){
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }

        ctx.stroke();

        //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        // Crop images via coordinates
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(borders[0][0][0], borders[0][0][1]);
        for(var i = 1; i < borders[0].length; i++){
            var p = borders[0][i];
            ctx.lineTo(borders[0][i][0], borders[0][i][1]);
        }
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.clip();









        // save images as files
        var file = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        var data = file.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
        var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
        fs.writeFile('cropped/image.png', buf);


        res.write('<html><body>');
        res.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
        res.write('</body></html>');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you are doing in your code... looks like you have a border array, why can you not draw each image to a new canvas and save individually from that?

Comment: I am going through the picture pixel by pixel, for each white pixel I check its surroundings, if there is a black pixel in the 8 squares around it I push the location in a border array.
Because I can have multiple borders which don't touch each other I afterwards run through the border array to sort the entries so every next step is connected by 1 pixel distance (x or y) to the step before,that way I can run the border array through a loop to draw the lines for the clip. if a border is closed but there are more unasigned border coordinates, a new border array is created.Multiple nested arrays

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to start by saying that it is way to complex for just one StackOverflow question, you got to reduce your problem to something small and precise if you want to get quick answers...

---

Breaking down your code it looks like, your border array is not working quite like I expected, see this:

https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_parse.html

There I got four canvas, you might recognize the stages of your code:

[image]

- First is the image just as is
- Second applied the filter and invert
- Third is all the borders in one place
- Forth is an animation of your border array

[image]

I was expecting that each item in borders was a Polygon, but it seems something is not quite right there yet, that is the first part you have to focus your time on.

Once you get the Polygons in the border array right, recreating those in separate images should be relatively easy, what I see that might complicate things a bit is the Polygon inside a Polygon like your star with a square hole, you can nest a lot of shapes and create some weird stuff, the logic around that can get really tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :)

I might have found a way to achieve what I'm looking for by calculating the height, width and location of each object and then moving the clip & overlay area to the top left corner on a new canvas. 

But as you said, my border doesn't seem to be exact and I am not sure why.
Each border array houses the perfectly sorted border coordinates, step by step so they touch each other, I checked it via Gimp and they match perfectly.
But somehow some sides also include white space. just 1 px thick.
I'm not sure how this can happen but I will have to get into it today.

Comment: Yes, calculating the height & width of each polygon is a simple Max and Min, if you wrote all that code that should not stop you... the border coords is your problem right now

Comment: I will go through the coordinates of the whole first star in gimp now. Checking if it starts bugging out somewhere. 
I thought the white 1px line that's beeing clipped might be a bug or something.
Because if I only go up/down left/right 1px each just along the black/white border, I can't really understand why some sites don't have white space but others do. 
I'm going only up/down left/right to not clip diagonally, but I believe somehow it still does it that way. 

I will post my solution once I find it. Atleast I hope I will find it.

Comment: The coordinates are correct, I still can't understand why the clipping path on some edges includes whitespaces and on others not. 
But as you pointed out I found a mayor bug in my edge detection algorithm. I can't handle 'U turns', or dead ends, whatever describes it better.

I'll probably create a new post only regarding the clipping error and try to get my border function work properly for now.

Comment: Ye, I was trying to figure out what is going on: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_parse.html#tip.jpg  _ _ _ while doing that your border detection could use some optimization the double loop to navigate all pixels has many operations under but the condition `Check around current white pixel if black one is near` we can avoid many of those if r != 255

Comment: Yea you're right, I'll check if r != 255 and just skip if that's true. Good idea.
I posted the clipping whitespace error as a new questions since that problem wasn't the topic of this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123327/nodejs-canvas-clip-region-not-accurate-random-whitespaces-along-edges

Due to the nature of my first star (no dead ends / U-Turns) the border should be working correct and my question be valid.

Comment: Why don't you post this project on GitHub, would be easier to collaborate/troubleshoot there

Comment: Done. 
https://github.com/ShivaHaze/ImageSeperator

I changed a bit, moved code parts to functions etc. 
The repo contains my current state.

Comment: Awesome! the move code parts to functions is something I did on my sample and forgot to mention