# NodeJS Canvas | Clip region not accurate - Random whitespaces along edges

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, clip

I'm facing a problem with the Canvas clip function.

I got the coordinates of the border of the first star on the following picture, but when I clip along the coordinates and then erase the rest I am left with some whitespaces around the star.
Some edges like the bottom right ones work fine, but the others don't.

I checked the coordinates by hand via Gimp and they're perfectly aligned along the border (clip border is running on the white pixels touching the outter black border)

[Coordinates Array](https://gist.github.com/ShivaHaze/d0ac7a354e88360c06415edea96546c5)

[image]

The result looks like this. I just can't understand why some edges don't contain any whitespaces but others do. This totally confuses me on how to use the clip function.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Do i need to work diagonally instead of always left/right up/down?

Comment: The right bottom side seem to be clipped correctly, my guess working diagonally would not make a difference... A minimal code snippet would tremendously help others troubleshoot your issue

Comment: The full repo is available here

https://github.com/ShivaHaze/ImageSeperator

Thanks alot for your help!
Edit: Is the full repo too much in this case? I can look up the code bits used for this actions if desired. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: To get more people interested in your question a minimal reproducible example is preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example